# Laravel 4 : trying to get variable from same page

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm getting an error which I think has more to do with logic than anything else but I can't quite seem to grasp how to overcome it.
So, I have a page with a simple form to search for a particular string in my database. But I want to have the result show up on the same page.

Here's what I have so far:

This is my Route.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('find', 'HomeController@find');
```

This is my HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('index');
}

public function search()
{
    return View::make('index');
}

public function find()
{
    $match = Input::get('find');
    if($match) {
        $results = Book::where('title', 'like', '%'.$match.'%')
                        ->orWhere('author', 'like', '%'.$match.'%')
                        ->get(); 
        return View::make('index', array('results', $results));
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_error', 'No string added!');
    }
}
```

And my View (index.blade.php):

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'find', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
    {{ Form::text('find', '', array('class' => 'search-query', 'placeholder' => 'Search')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
    @if (Session::has('flash_error'))
            {{ Session::get('flash_error') }}
    @endif
@foreach ($results as $result)
        {{$result->title}}
@endforeach
```

(eventually the foreach will be replaced by some ajax loading to display each result)

And the error says "undefined variable: results" and shows the foreach.
I get why that error shows up since on the first pass to this page the results haven't been loaded yet but how can I overcome this? I really want the data to be shown on the same page without having to go to another page to display them.
Like I said, I think this is mostly logic related (although I'm very new to Laravel so it might be that too)

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Not sure if this was a typo when copying to SO, but in the `find()` method of your `HomeController`, the method `orwhere()` does not exist in the query builder. `orWhere()` does, however.

Comment: Also, just curious: What is the purpose of `gen_index()`. Why not move the `View::make()` to `find()`?

Comment: The orWhere() was a typo, however you're right the gen_index doesn't really do anything! I don't know why it seemed natural to me to export it like that. I updated my question in consequence. Any idea about my initial problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that in your use of `index.blade.php` in multiple controllers, you forgot which controllers provide which variables (and as a result, which variables may be omitted).

When you request `/` (`HomeController@index`), `index.blade.php` is rendered, but since no `$results` are passed to the view, you see the Undefined Variable warning. This is not a problem in `HomeController@find`, because you define `$results`. To combat this, you'll need to do something along the lines of an `isset()` check on `$results` before you `foreach` over it. Like so:

```
@if(isset($results))
    @foreach ($results as $result)
        {{$result->title}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Your logic may vary based on your page's layout (you might want to add an else and display some alternate placeholder content).

---

Also, if abstracting the call to `View::make()` with `$results` into `index_gen()` isn't keeping your code DRY, then I'd suggest replacing it in `find()` with the call to `View::make()`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted !

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass an associative array as your second param of the make method

```
return View::make('index', array('results' => $results);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the "undefined variable: results" from the View even with your suggested changes